# Selenium using python Project in VS code

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I can't find the selenium python library on vs code, despite it being installed as shown in the screenshot below? (python)
problem : Import "selenium" could not be resolved.
[vs code capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L65lo.png)

need for help please ! a solution !

Comment: are using a virtual environment?

Comment: did you get any error when you run your script ?

Comment: @mohamed : no, I did not receive an error message /  no virtual environnement !

Comment: `pip install selenium` run this in cmd, restart visual studio and make sure the PYTHONPATH environment variable points to the correct location where the selenium library is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't choose the correct python interpreter, so you didn't get the pylance intellisense.

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the interpreter where the package was installed.